# How can I use a JQuery slideDown() without affecting the rest of the page?

Tags: jquery, css

I currently have a list of results in "row" classes. These rows are split into two pieces, and "span8" and a "span4". The span 4 is hidden until a function calls for it to slideDown. However, it has a height greater than that of the row, so when it slides down, the rest of the page gets shifted down slightly. Is there some way to allow it to go "through" other elements? Kind of like in MS Word when you have an image and position it "through" so that it can sit on top of text without affecting it.

Comment: `position: absolute;` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position it absolutely, and add "position: relative" to your row class.

Another option would be to set visibility, rather than display: none.  This will keep the height from jumping.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a container with `height: 0; overflow:visible;` and set the actual content to have `overflow: hidden`. Then when its height changes it should overlap the other content. The container could also have the row height rather than 0 for consistency.

You'll see in this JSfiddle that the grey div under the top container is not displaced by the text "content" (half shown for giggles)
http://jsfiddle.net/W2HP3/1/

Comment: Position absolute inside a relative also works, probably better, but I thought I'd throw out the other option. Problem here is getting a background on the content would take a bit of work.